# Using a vendor not namespaced into laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a vendor that I want to use that was originally created for Symphony and it isn't namespaced into Laravel, I'm not too sure on how to make it work.

Here is the package: https://github.com/caponica/AmazonMwsComplete

I read somewhere that I would have to add `psr-0` into composer and I already have the `psr-4` default data in composer so I added:

```
"psr-0": {
          "MWS\\": "caponica/amazon-mws-complete"
        },
```

The `MWS\\` I just made up since I wasn't too sure what to do and the other portion is the vendor folders, figured that's what I needed.

So, when I tried to call the class into routes for testing I tried:

```
use MWS\CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\AmazonClient\MwsProductClient;
```

and it keeps saying that the MwsProductClient class isn't found.

Comment: try to map it in the "autoload" : "classmap" array of your composer.json

Comment: just did that and it didnt work. i did it like this:  "caponica/amazon-mws-complete" in the classmap autoload section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because you are trying to use wrong path and namespace. Accrording to the source code of package you are trying to use the namespace you want to load is `namespace CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\AmazonClient;`
So you need to include this into you composer.json file:

`"psr-0": {
          "CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\\": "caponica/amazon-mws-complete/src"
        },`

I'm not 100% sure but it should work. Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` before using.

If it doesn't work add a comment here and I will check it again.

UPDATE:
So I managed it to work using PSR-4 autoload:

```
"psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\\": "vendor/caponica/amazon-mws-complete/src/CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete",
      "AmazonPhpClientLibrary\\": "vendor/caponica/amazon-mws-complete/src/AmazonPhpClientLibrary"
    }
```

But note that this library is quite outdated and it's documentation doesn't fits it's code.

Comment: nope didnt work. i got, Class 'CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\AmazonClient\MwsProductClient' not found. i have on the top of my router use CaponicaAmazonMwsComplete\AmazonClient\MwsProductClient and it says that it cannot be found.